# MySQL : case sensitive field name while creating table

Tags: mysql, database-migration

My question today is pretty simple and self-explanatory: is there a way to make a table field case sensitive? I am trying to create a table with all alphabet letters both lower and upper case as theyre names, while the data itself is either a number or a boolean.

```
 ________________________
| Column Name | Datatype |
|¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯|¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯|
|      a      |    INT   |
|      b      |  TinyINT |
|      c      |    INT   |
|      d      |    INT   |
|     ...     |    ...   |
|      A      |    INT   |
|      B      |  TinyINT |
|      C      |    INT   |
|      D      |  TinyINT |
|     ...     |    INT   |
 ´´´´´´´´´´´´´´´´´´´´´´´´
```

The main problem I encounter is this error

> Error 1060: Duplicate column name 'A' SQL Statement: CREATE TABLE ...

I have already searched for a solution but what I found was either the **BINARY** method, but it works only on characters or just renaming my upper case fields to something else. This is part of a data migration from a CouchDB database to MySQL so the field names are pretty important as to make the whole program work fine.

Any suggestions? Also if you have any tips on migrating from a NoSQL db to a SQL one feel free to share them!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[The manual says](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/identifier-case-sensitivity.html),

> Column, index, stored routine, and event names are not case sensitive on any platform, nor are column aliases.

So a port depending on case sensitivity in column names won't work correctly.

It also has a lot to say about the case sensitivity of database and table names. That depends in intricate ways on the database server's host OS.

In my opinion @Strawberry is right. You're asking for trouble if you build a database depending on case sensitive identifiers.

Comment: Got it! Thanks for the precise and well rounded answer, too bad now I have to revisit and refactor all my databases functionalities :-/

Comment: Problem is when you get a already settled DB, it's my case. PHP indexes are case sensitive, so migrating to Oracle I will have to review 3.450 PHP files and convert indexes, it's a nightmare!